# = gets.chomp ... not working in terminal

Tags: ruby

```
puts 'Hi, What\'s Your Name?'
name = gets.chomp
puts = 'Nice, to meet you ' + name
```

When I run in terminal,  it allows me to type in name. "Bob"
But it stops.  Does not put   "Nice to meet you Bob"

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: When I run in the terminal  it stops at Bob and does not put Nice to meet you Bob

Comment: I am not getting the "Nice to Meet You Bob"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
puts = 'Nice, to meet you ' + name
```

to

```
puts 'Nice, to meet you ' + name
```

otherwise you're storing the result in the variable `puts` rather than printing it out.

Comment: Thanks ... it was the = sign!